# Checking if the second list is half the size of first list

Tags: prolog

I am a noob prolog programmer and facing a difficulty with one of the basic problems that have been given in the book where I am learning from. The question. The question basically asks us to write down a Prolog procedure that takes two lists as arguments, and succeeds if the first list is twice the size of the second list and the two lists start with the same element. The procedure should return false if the two lists are empty.

For example it should return true if we pass the query:

```
a2b([a,a,a,a],[a,b]).
```

and would fail with a query like:

```
a2b([a,a],[a,b,b,b]).
```

I don't know how to solve this problem recursively, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the request about lengths:

```
/* empty list fulfills request */   
a2b_length([],[]). 
/* non-empty: discard two elements of first list, 
                one of second list, and verify
                remainder */
a2b_length([_,_|Q1],[_|Q2]) :- 
   a2b_length(Q1,Q2).
```

Now, we can add the requirement "starts by the same term and are non empty", and write the last clause:

```
a2b([X,_|Q1],[X|Q2]) :-
   a2b_length(Q1,Q2).
```

Comment: Your solution suggests that given two empty lists, one is twice as long as the other. But you're on the right track.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure than if length of first list is zero and length of second one is zero, first length is twice second one.

Comment: How would the clause that you posted return false for empty lists? I couldn't get that part.

Comment: The main clause "a2b" is composed of a single rule with left part: a2b( [X,_|Q1] , [X|Q2] ) :- ... . This rule request that first argument was two terms (X and _) followed by any other amount of them (list Q1), second argument must be one term (X) followed by any others (list Q2). When testing "a2b( [], [] )", empty list doesn't matches any of these conditions. In addition, it request also that both first terms was equal, but this is not important for the subject of empty list.

Comment: Nice. A minor stylistic improvement: `a2b(Xs, Ys) :- Xs = [X|_], Ys = [X|_], a2b_length(Xs, Ys).` In this manner, the requirement "starts with the same element" is independent of what `a2b_length/2` describes. Imagine, later on, you realise that it's not about the double length, but rather triple length. You would only need to change `a2b_length/2` but not this clause.

Answer (score 1):

Cute problem. It can be solved using the following code:

```
% fail of the first element of each list don't unify
% or if one or both lists are empty
a2b([First| List1], [First| List2]) :-
    % calculate the length of the second list
    % while traversing both lists in parallel
    a2b_first(List2, 1, N, List1, Rest1),
    % check that the length of the rest of the first
    % list is equal to the length of the second list
    a2b_second(Rest1, N).

a2b_first([], N, N, Tail1, Tail1).
a2b_first([_| Tail2], N0, N, [_| Tail1], Rest1) :-
    N1 is N0 + 1,
    a2b_first(Tail2, N1, N, Tail1, Rest1).

a2b_second([], 0).
a2b_second([_| Tail1], N) :-
    M is N - 1,
    a2b_second(Tail1, M).
```

Of course, there's a simpler (but not as fun to code!) solution:

```
% fail of the first element of each list don't unify
% or if one or both lists are empty
a2b([First| List1], [First| List2]) :-
    length([First| List1], N1),
    length([First| List2], N2),
    N1 is 2 * N2.
```

The `length/2` predicate is usually available either as a built-in predicate or as a library predicate.

For learning Prolog, studying the first solution is interesting. For example, it exemplifies how to take advantage of first-argument indexing and how to use accumulators for writing predicates that are tail-recursive (and thus space efficient).

Also, the first solution can be more efficient than the second solution. In the second solution, we always traverse both lists to the end to find their lengths. But, in the first solution, that is not always necessary.

Comment: Got it! Doesn't look so bad now after all haha. Thanks a lot buddy! :)

Comment: You welcome. But I would select the other answer (by "passabe por aqui"; cute username! :-) as the accepted answer. Although it uses three clauses while the `length/2` based answer uses one clause, it's efficient and nicely illustrates that using readily available built-in/library predicates don't always result in the most elegant solutions.

Comment: Both versions do not terminate for `a2b(Xs,[a]).`

Comment: @false The question states (emphasis mine): "... write down a Prolog procedure that **takes two lists as arguments**...". Could it be that most answers to most Prolog questions here in SO are written considering **stated requirements** and reasonable assumptions?

Comment: It is common to state the semantics of predicates only for the ground case - and to hope for the best for more general cases.

Answer (score 0):

Don't overthink things: just describe the solution and let Prolog sort it out.

The solution doesn't require counting or predicates other than its trivial self. It's all pattern matching. We have a special (terminating case), asserting that a list of length 2 is twice as long as a list of length 1 (which should be pretty obvious):

```
is_twice_as_long_as( [_,_] , [_] ) .
```

Then there is the general case, which asserts that given two lists of arbitrary length, the left is twice as long as the right IF we can (A) remove 2 items from the left, (B) remove 1 item from right, and recursively assert that their respective remainders are likewise twice as long:

```
is_twice_as_long_as( [_,_|A] , [_|B] ) :- is_twice_as_long_as( A , B ) .
```

Giving us the finished product:

```
is_twice_as_long_as( [_,_]   , [_]   ) .
is_twice_as_long_as( [_,_|A] , [_|B] ) :- is_twice_as_long_as( A , B ) .
```

Easy!

**Edited to note** the requirement that the two lists begin with the same element:

Depending on how that is interpreted...

- this requires that the lists have a common head on each iteration:

  ```
  is_twice_as_long_as( [A,_]   , [A]   ) .
  is_twice_as_long_as( [A,_|L] , [A|R] ) :- is_twice_as_long_as( L , R ) .
  ```
- this does the check for a common head just once::

  ```
  is_twice_as_long_as( [A|As] , [A|Bs] ) :-
    is_2x([A|As],[A|Bs]) .

  is_2x( [_,_]   , [_] ) .
  is_2x( [_,_|L] , [_|R] ) :- is_2x( L , R ) .
  ```

Comment: The question states that "a2b([a,a,a,a],[a,b])." is true, thus you can discard first option at "Depending on how that is interpreted..."